# How to query to get below unique result?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query was:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT _to, _from FROM message;
```

and it gave output as:-

```
 _to  _from  time

sam     jeet  16/01/17 00:18:27.7780
jeet     sam  16/01/17 00:18:26.7780
bro      sis  16/01/17 00:18:20.7780
sis       bro 16/01/17 00:18:23.7780
abc      def  16/01/17 00:18:21.7780
```

It gives the correct result but It is not giving what I want.
 i need output as below:

```
sam  jeet 16/01/17 00:18:27.7780
sis  bro  16/01/17 00:18:23.7780
abc   def 16/01/17 00:18:21.7780
```

That is jeet,sam should be same as sam,jeet and so it should not be repeated.Similiarly with sis,bro.
And out of two the one selected should have latest time

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: add where `_to <= _from`

Comment: Please tag ONLY the DBMS you are using

Comment: @vkp its content are not only integer but also strings, For taking example i have taken numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN _to < _from THEN _from
            ELSE _to
         END,
         CASE 
            WHEN _to >= _from THEN _from
            ELSE _to
         END
FROM message
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN _to < _from THEN _from
            ELSE _to
         END,
         CASE 
            WHEN _to >= _from THEN _from
            ELSE _to
         END
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f5b2/2)

If you are using MySQL the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT LEAST(_to, _from),
       GREATEST(_to, _from)
FROM message
GROUP BY LEAST(_to, _from),
       GREATEST(_to, _from)
```

Comment: `least` and `greatest` are also available?

Comment: What if data are in strings and not just number. Here only for reference i have taken numbers

Comment: @ChandanBera It's the same. You can use comparison operators with string as well in SQL.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos your answer works but what if I have one more column say "time" and out of two (a,b) or( b,a) distinct I need the one having max(time)